# Ограничить вывод внутренних ссылок из файла

Tags: php

Есть вот такой небольшой код на странице новости:

```
$new_text = nl2br($text);
$file = file('tags.txt');
$str = $new_text;
foreach($file as $v) {
    $v1 = explode(":", $v);
    $str = preg_replace("/(".$v1[0].".*?)\b/iu", "<a href='http://".$v1[1]."'>\\1</a>", $str, 1);
}
echo $str;
```

Файл tags.txt:

```
Ольга Бузова:site.ru/olga_buzova/
Ольгу Бузову:site.ru/olga_buzova/
Ольге Бузовой:site.ru/olga_buzova/
```

Переменная $text с текстом:

```
Ольга Бузова заявила, что является певицей, однако Ольге Бузовой не поверили.
```

В результате всего этого на выводе получаю следующее:

```
<a href="http://site.ru/olga_buzova/">Ольга Бузова</a> заявила, что является певицей, однако <a href="http://site.ru/olga_buzova/">Ольге Бузовой</a> не поверили.
```

Код расставляет ссылки из файла tags.txt с анкорами, если они встречаются в тексте. Все хорошо, прямые дубли он распознает и не вставляет, однако как из текста удалить второй анкор "Ольге Бузовой", если найден первый "Ольга Бузова"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Как из текста удалить второй анкор "Ольге Бузовой", если найден первый "Ольга Бузова"?*

Объявить временный массив, в который сохранять имеющиеся URL'ы, и проверять на каждой итерации, нет ли в массиве такого адреса:

```
$text = 'Ольга Бузова заявила, что является певицей, однако Ольге Бузовой не поверили.';

$file = [
    'Ольга Бузова:site.ru/olga_buzova/',
    'Ольгу Бузову:site.ru/olga_buzova/',
    'Ольге Бузовой:site.ru/olga_buzova/'
];

$temp = [];

foreach ($file as $v) {
    list($name, $url) = explode(":", $v);
    if (! in_array($url, $temp)) {
        $text = preg_replace("~$name~iu", "<a href='http://$url'>$0</a>", $text);
        $temp[] = $url;
    }
}

echo $text;
```

Comment: Все отлично работает, благодарю!